# Interactable Grid in ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to draw a rectangular (not quadratic) "support" grid: Users can hover an tile of this grid and place a specific object there. E.g. I hover over (x:0 y:15) and I click, I get an object at (x:0 y:15).

[image]

This Grid was done with a PlaneGeometry and drawn as a wireframe (in r58).

```
new THREE.PlaneGeometry(x,y,16, 9);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x004488,
    wireframe: true
});
mat.color.r = r;
mat.color.g = g;
mat.color.b = b;
```

After I updated the code base to r94 I get now triangles instead of quads for the different tiles of the plane.

I tried the following:

**Drawing lines**: After looking at the source code of GridHelper, I created a rectangular version. It looks very nice but the hit detection of a tile is off. Hit detection is implemented with a Raycaster. I think the problem is, thaht lines only get detected if the mouse is actually over a line. With the PlaneGeometry the mouse could be inside a tile and the geometry was detected correctly.

**Drawing a PlaneGeometry with a Texture** The next think I tried was using a PlaneGeometry with a custom Texture, like this:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = 32;
canvas.width = 32;
context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, 32, 32);
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = color.getStyle();
context.stroke();

// canvas contents will be used for a texture
let texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);

texture.needsUpdate = true;

let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
// let material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
material.map = texture;
material.flatShading = true;
material.fog = false;
material.lights = false;
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
material.transparent = true;

return material;
```

Now hit detection works like a charm, as it did with r54, but now it looks very ugly if the viewing angle is flat:

[image]

I'm running out of ideas, so I would appreciate a hint or something how I can draw nice looking grid, which is one geometry so the current hit detection system can be used.

**TL;DR;** I need a grid, which behaves like a PlaneGeometry (hit detection) but only drawing squares instead of triangles.

Comment: this YouTube video shows exactly that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQbfy8QP8Lc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a grid, built from lines. For that, you can create `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry()` and change its `.index` propery. Then use this geometry with `THREE.LineSegments()`.

[image]

[Reference](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/grids-of-waves-shaders/1168)

And the source code for changing the indices:

```
  Object.assign(THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry.prototype, {
    toGrid: function() {
      let segmentsX = this.parameters.widthSegments || 1;
      let segmentsY = this.parameters.heightSegments || 1;
      let indices = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < segmentsY + 1; i++) {
        let index11 = 0;
        let index12 = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < segmentsX; j++) {
          index11 = (segmentsX + 1) * i + j;
          index12 = index11 + 1;
          let index21 = index11;
          let index22 = index11 + (segmentsX + 1);
          indices.push(index11, index12);
          if (index22 < ((segmentsX + 1) * (segmentsY + 1) - 1)) {
            indices.push(index21, index22);
          }
        }
        if ((index12 + segmentsX + 1) <= ((segmentsX + 1) * (segmentsY + 1) - 1)) {
          indices.push(index12, index12 + segmentsX + 1);
        }
      }
      this.setIndex(indices);
      return this;
    }
  });
```

Using:

```
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 5, 10, 5).toGrid();
var gridPlane = new THREE.LineSegments(planeGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "yellow"}));
```

Comment: What exactly does this "rewrite" of the indices do? Removing the triangles or...? BTW, very cool picture

Comment: @morpheus05 it allows you to use so-called ["indexed lines"](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lines#webgl_buffergeometry_lines_indexed) technique. Thus, there are no faces, just lines. Having this, the approach with raycaster should be changed to work with lines. Or, you can have a usual plane( for raycaster) and a grid atop of it. In the reference link, have look at the jsfiddle and its source code.